# Bazel: settings_bundle

Tags: ios, bazel

I set up

```
config_setting(
name = "qa"
values = {"define": "env=qa"},
)

config_setting(
name = "dev"
values = {"define": "env=dev"},
)
```

Now how can I get bazel to include a *settings_bundle* only if it matches qa or dev?

```
ios_application (
name = myApp,
bundle_id = "com.app.myapp",
...
#set it only if qa or dev otherwise no settings_bundle
settings_bundle = ":SettingsBundle"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a `select()`, something like this:

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")
bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

`BUILD`:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:selects.bzl", "selects")

...

ios_application(
  ...
  settings_bundle = selects.with_or({
      (":qa", ":dev"): ":SettingsBundle",
      "//conditions:default": None,
  }),
)
```

I'm not actually sure if the `None` for `//conditions:default` will work, it might require that you have some dummy settings bundle.

See:

- https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/master/docs/selects_doc.md

Comment: The _dummy_ settings work as I have tried it. The side effect is it leaves a blank page in settings. I'm evaluating **None** and will report findings.

Comment: **None** gave me what I needed.